# Is there any control that can show photos like "Photos" in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Does iOS have any control to show photos like the Photos application?

I'd like a control to manage albums, photos, show an album list, and show photos, like the built-in Photos, or the Facebook app.

Comment: Photos.app has different ways of showing photos. Which one?

Comment: I want to make my app show photo like "Photos" of iOS or Photo of iOS Facebook app.

Comment: the way facebook app shows them is using the api 'three20' freely available for use, with lots of documentation and other goodies in there besides just the photo view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can download the latest sample code [PhotoScroller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/) which contains the similar implementation of photos app. Here swipe & individual photo zoom has been implemented for both orientations using UIScrollViews and CATiledLayer.

It doesn't contain thumbnail view code however it's relatively easy to create using a simple UIScrollView coding. And as per the comment of Jesse Naugher, you can also use [Three20](http://github.com/facebook/three20) static library written by Joe Hewitt.

[Scrolling Madness](http://github.com/andreyvit/ScrollingMadness) is relatively easy to use from both of the above mentioned.

Another library on GitHub - [FGallery-iPhone](https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone)

Answer (score 1):

Try this Project on Github : [SFAlbumApp](https://github.com/constantineSafronov/SFAlbumApp)